# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'match.params.id'

Tags: reactjs, parameters, use-effect

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'match.params.id'. Either includes it or remove the dependency array, this is the error I continuously get while using useEffect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let data = await getPost(match.params.id);
      console.log(data);
      setPost(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work, need to include 'match.params.id' in useEffect dependency array,

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let data = await getPost(match.params.id);
      console.log(data);
      setPost(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [match.params.id]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your dependency array in useEffect hook like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let data = await getPost(match.params.id);
      console.log(data);
      setPost(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [match.params.id]);
```

According to the offical react documentation - `the dependency array should includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect.`

You can check here for more info - [Official doc link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

Comment: no, still i didn't get the relevent output.